# Do you have any Tips for Magento 2 SEO? Help me

Tags: magento-2.1, seo, best-practice

I am a newbie in Magento 2 and I am learning about SEO. Is there anyone who knows about Magento 2 seo best-practices?

Comment: Yes, there is an easy, fast and legit way to do SEO for Magento by using Extensions.
You can get the extension https://marketplace.magento.com/fme-advanced-sitemap-generator.html

Answer (score 1):

Mark,

to learn about Magento 2 SEO features and compare them with Magento 1, follow this link:

http://blog.mageworx.com/2015/08/magento-2-seo-features/

Additionally, you can check out this podcast about SEO capabilities of Magento 2:
http://2xecommerce.com/podcast/ep55/

and this interview about today's Magento 2 SEO challenges: 
http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/05/magento-2-and-todays-seo-challenges/

If you want to dig deeper into details, read these article about Magento 2 SEO mistakes to avoid:

http://inchoo.net/online-marketing/common-magento-2-seo-mistakes/

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 comes with many new improvements in SEO.It geared up to improve the default SEO capabilities.

**Following are the changes found in Magento 2 SEO.**

1. Product Page Optimization
2. XML Sitemap Rich Snippets Robots.txt
3. Schema.org Integration
4. Product Image Labels Related Products
5. Upsells, and Cross-sells Universal Google Analytics
6. eCommerce Tracking and AdWords Conversion
7. Google Tag Manager
8. SEO Configuration
9. Pagination Optimization
10. Layered Navigation Category
11. Page Optimization

These SEO improvements in Magento 2.0 cover important aspects to making sure your website gets higher rankings. For more details visit: https://www.mconnectmedia.com/blog/magento-2-seo-improvements/

Answer (score 0):

To make Magento 2 store successful it is highly recommended to make it fully SEO optimize. Here are the tips for Magento 2 store that can help you:

- Optimize Product Page
- XML Sitemap
- Robots.txt
- Rich Snippets
- Schema.org Integration
- Product Image Labels
- Related Products, Upsells, and Cross-sells
- Universal Google Analytics, Ecommerce Tracking, and AdWords
  Conversion